# Do QR codes change "resolution" incrementally?

Tags: qr-code

When encoding text into a QR code, the longer the text is, the more columns and rows are needed to display it. This makes the QR code harder to scan, and requires it to be printed larger.

Do QR codes gain resolution(columns and widths) incrementally (5,6,7,8), or in steps (8,16,32), and if so, what are the steps?

See the images on this page. Note the difference between "Loads of Data" and "Little Data".
http://qrcode.meetheed.com/question7.php?s=s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizes increases in steps of 4 "modules", a module being one little black or white square.

The smallest QR Codes (version 1) are 21x21 modules, version 2 is 25x25, and so on until the practically-impossible-to-scan [version 40](http://www.picxi.net/img/27032011-qrversionsfull.png) which is 177x177 modules.

Source: the "ISO 18004" norm defining QR Codes (I can't link to it since it's not available for free...)

Comment: [This page](http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html) explains it well enough.